# LinkButton click by JavaScript not work with google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

LinkButton click by JavaScript not work with google chrome.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSearch" OnClick="lnkSearch_Click" Text="abc" />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Click Link" onclick="abc();" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function abc() {
      document.getElementById('<%= lnkSearch.ClientID %>').click();
 }
</script>
```

Any one has idea?

Answer (score 0):

try after adding following code to OnPreInit method of base page.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.UserAgent != null && (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0))  // added for compatibility issues with chrome 
    {
        this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
    }

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

refer original post [asp.NET LinkButton not working in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259489/asp-net-linkbutton-not-working-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer as follow

`function Search() {
        window.location.href = document.getElementById('<%= lnkSearch.ClientID %>');
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

For asp linkbutton a client click should be:

```
OnClientClick="abc(); return false"
```